# render pdf.js page like real html elements not canvas or svg?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, pdf.js, pdfjs-dist

I am trying to make simple mobile UI that could be reading pdf, but I am planning to add many features by using my own made pdf read, not just by using the viewer made by pdf.js team, so I was asking if there is any way of rendering pdf as just an HTML with elements, as they did on their viewer, I am not comfortable with canvas, any help guys, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

okay guys i finally found out the way
`pdf.js` has a method called `getTextContent()` these method is called on each page as you render a page

**simply get every page on you document**

```js
PDFJS.getDocument(url)
  .then(function(pdf) {

    // Get div#container and cache it for later use
    var container = document.getElementById("container");

    // Loop from 1 to total_number_of_pages in PDF document
    for (var i = 1; i <= pdf.numPages; i++) {

        // Get desired page
        pdf.getPage(i).then(function(page) {

          var scale = 1.5;
          var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
          var div = document.createElement("div");

          // Set id attribute with page-#{pdf_page_number} format
          div.setAttribute("id", "page-" + (page.pageIndex + 1));

          // This will keep positions of child elements as per our needs
          div.setAttribute("style", "position: relative");

          // Append div within div#container
          container.appendChild(div);

          // Create a new Canvas element
          var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

          // Append Canvas within div#page-#{pdf_page_number}
          div.appendChild(canvas);

          var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
          canvas.height = viewport.height;
          canvas.width = viewport.width;

          var renderContext = {
            canvasContext: context,
            viewport: viewport
          };

          // Render PDF page
          page.render(renderContext);
        });
    }
});
```

**get every page's text content**
remember that it is continuous codes from previous ones
then inside `page.render()` add modify it like this way

```js
// Render PDF page
page.render(renderContext)
  .then(function() {
    // Get text-fragments
    return page.getTextContent();
  })
  .then(function(textContent) {
    // Create div which will hold text-fragments
    var textLayerDiv = document.createElement("div");

    // Set it's class to textLayer which have required CSS styles
    textLayerDiv.setAttribute("class", "textLayer");

    // Append newly created div in `div#page-#{pdf_page_number}`
    div.appendChild(textLayerDiv);

    // Create new instance of TextLayerBuilder class
    var textLayer = new TextLayerBuilder({
      textLayerDiv: textLayerDiv, 
      pageIndex: page.pageIndex,
      viewport: viewport
    });

    // Set text-fragments
    textLayer.setTextContent(textContent);

    // Render text-fragments
    textLayer.render();
  });
```

for full tutorial on how to do it go [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/custom-pdf-rendering/)

Answer (score -2):

I don't think there's such option.

The only way of displaying pdf files in a browser (not every and not mobile browsers) using native support is by passing url to iframe/embed tag `<iframe src="url_to_your.pdf">`

But note that this still doesn't result in HTML output you are looking for.

Comment: then how do they do for their viewer, take a look and inspect this https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html